# Angular 2 service not being injected into component

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-injection, angular2-services

I have a service defined in my Angular2 (2.0.0-beta.0) application.  It's something like this:

```
import {Injectable} from "angular2/core";

@Injectable()
export class MyService {
    constructor() {

    }

    getSomething() {
        return 'something';
    }
}
```

I have it listed in my bootstrap() function in my main app file so that it should be made available to my code in general:

```
bootstrap(App, [MyService, SomeOtherService, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES[);
```

Sometimes I can't use the service in a component, even though I have something like `myService:MyService` in the component `constructor()` function, like this:

```
import {MyService} from '../services/my.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    directives: [],
    providers: [],
    pipes: [],
    template: `
    <div><button (click)="doStuff()">Click Me!</button></div>
    `
})
export MyComponent {
    constructor(myService:MyService) {} // note the private keyword

    doStuff() {
        return this.myService.getSomething();
    }
}
```

In other places it works fine.  In places where it doesn't work, I get a message like if I try to access it:

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getSomething' of undefined
```

It basically means the service was not injected.

What is causing it to not be injected?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that it appears that the dependency injection won't work unless you have the injected objects in the constructor marked as either `private` or `public`.

Adding either of those two things in front of the service injection in my component's constructor made it work fine:

```
import {MyService} from '../services/my.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    directives: [],
    providers: [],
    pipes: [],
    template: `
    <div><button (click)="doStuff()">Click Me!</button></div>
    `
})
export MyComponent {
    constructor(private myService:MyService) {} // note the private keyword

    doStuff() {
        return this.myService.getSomething();
    }
}
```

Comment: I've been declaring them before the constructor and using `this.MyService = MyService` but I like this method..

Comment: I have mine exactly the same as yours and I still get 'myservice' is not defined error at runtime

Comment: I have done what you are saying but still not working and giving this same error

Comment: check the this value, for me it is the value of where it came from

Answer (score 12):

This behaviour is totally normal.

In the constructor method of the component when you don't add the ***private*** or ***public*** keyword the ***myService*** variable is evaluated as a local variable, so it's destroyed at the end of the method call.

When you add ***private*** or ***public*** keyword, TypeScript will add the variable to the class property, so you can later call the property with ***this*** keyword.

```
constructor(myService: MyService) {
  alert(myService.getSomething());
  // This will works because 'myService', is declared as an argument
  // of the 'constructor' method.
}

doStuff() {
  return (this.myService.getSomething());
  // This will not works because 'myService' variable is a local variable
  // of the 'constructor' method, so it's not defined here.
}
```

Comment: [Typescript docs](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#classes-privatepublic-modifiers): "The keywords `public` and `private` also give you a shorthand for creating and initializing members of your class, by creating parameter properties. The properties let you create and initialize a member in one step."